# Bundler and bundler-only - suppress duplicate gem warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

I am using bundler on my gemfile for executing the application, and found it convenient to use `bundler-only` to be able to pick only a subset of gems that are needed for deployments only.

So on my deployment machine, I use `bundle-only` that will only install gems namespaced under the `deploy` group.

However, because of this I need to duplicate some gem (eg. my deployments need to send a notification to slack, so I have some notifier gems both in my global namespace and my :deploy-only namespace.
This cause several warnings

> Your Gemfile lists the gem slack-notifier (>= 0) more than once. You
>   should probably keep only one of them. While it's not a problem now,
>   it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later

Is there a way to suppress the warnings ? (if possible those gems only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative is to maintain a list of all `groups`, and systematically include `, groups: groups`

```
# Gemfile
groups = [:deploy, :x, :y, :z, ...] # Maintain this list as you add groups

# Gems needed except in deploy
gem :a
gem :b
...

# Gems that are also required for deploy
gem :d1, groups: groups
gem :d2, groups: groups

# Gems that are required ONLY in deploy

group :deploy do 
  gem :dep_only1
  gem :dep_only2
end
```

So the following works without warning

```
bundle --without deploy # Will ignore deploy group
bundle-only deploy # Will install only deploy gems including those that are also needed by the app
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't list gems more than once. That warning is there for good reason.

You can group gems under multiple namespaces at once within a `Gemfile`, like so:

```
group :deploy, :somethingelse do
  gem 'slack-notifier'
end

group :deploy do
  # Deploy-ONLY gems
end

group :somethingelse
  # Somethingelse-ONLY gems
end
```

Or if you prefer, you can do this grouping inline:

```
gem 'slack-notifier', group: [:deploy, :somethingelse]
```

For more information, read the [bundler documentation](http://bundler.io/groups.html) on Gemfile groups.

Comment: The warning doesn't know about the `bundle-only` gem which is used to install only gems listed under a given namespace.

Comment: That's besides the point. There is still no need for you to list the gems more than once. Doing so goes against bundler's guidelines (hence the warning above), and nor is it recommended in [the `bundle-only` README](https://github.com/MOZGIII/bundle-only). By listing the `slack-notifier` gem twice, you are creating an unnecessary risk of future version conflicts - e.g. when running a standard `bundle install` command.

Comment: If you would like more specific advice on how to structure your whole `Gemfile`, you could include it in your post - and I will take a look.